# Understanding SQL throwing Conversion errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

I have a SQL Server Agent job that fails once in a while throwing a conversion error varchar to int.

The crazy part is after the error has been thrown and went I run the same code, it runs ok.

Then if re-run the job again it runs fine. After a few days, however, this happens again (the job is scheduled to run daily). Please, can someone help me understand why this happens and how to fix?

I am using SQL Server 2017
Data types: Col1 = char(6),Col2 = varchar(25),Col3 = char(15),col4 = char(6),lev1 = char(6)

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2,
    REPLACE(col3,'_','') AS col3
FROM 
    TableName
WHERE 
    col4 IN (SELECT DISTINCT lev1 
             FROM viewName WITH (NOLOCK))

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    0, 'Unassigned', 0
```

Comment: Add the code to your question of the part that you know is failing.  Even though it works when you run it manually, it's still a lot more for us to work from than nothing.

Comment: I posted the Code without the actual table names and columns. I hope that helps.

Comment: Column definitions are very relevant here; please provide them

Comment: what about the data type for col4?  Perhaps comparing col4 with lev1 is the issue. `where convert(char(6),col4) in (select distinct lev1 ...`.

Comment: Until you have mastered basic tsql, [stop using hints generally](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidlean/2009/04/05/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas/) and the nolock hint specifically. Don't use the nolock hint until you understand the possible consequences and are prepared to handle them accordingly.

Comment: `col3` is `VARCHAR` in the first `SELECT`, but `INT` in the second `SELECT`.

Answer (score 3):

`col1` and `col3` are defined as character data types, but in the second select of the union, you have hard coded integers. Try making those strings instead.

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2,
    REPLACE(col3,'_','') AS col3
FROM 
    TableName
WHERE 
    col4 IN (SELECT DISTINCT lev1 
             FROM viewName WITH (NOLOCK))

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    '0', 'Unassigned', '0'
```

Comment: That could very well be, I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: But, do you know why sometimes if fails sometimes it won't? I am trying to understand the theory behind it, please.

Comment: @Senay My _guess_ would be that sometimes `col1` and `col3` only return numeric values in the first query and they are implicitly converted to INTs to match the hard coded data in the second query. At other times, those columns return other characters, and the implicit conversion fails. By making the values in the second query strings, the data types will match and the implicit conversion to INT will be eliminated.

Comment: Thank you so much.